# Adding all occurrences of a string

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am stuck on a section of code. In this code I am trying to get all the occurrences of characters(amino) in a string(protein). There are two letters( ['M','L'] ) that I need to find in the string. When I use .count I get 1 for "M" and 10 for "L". The problem is I cannot find the right way to add both of the counts from both letters together to get 11.

```
protein = "MSRSLLLRFLLFLLLLPPLP"
aa = ['M', 'L']
    
    for aminos in aa:
        if aminos in protein:
            protein.count(aminos)
```

Comment: try `sum(protein.count(aminos) for aminos in aa if aminos in protein)`

Comment: It gives me an error : 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The following is one of the many.

```py
from collections import Counter

protein = "MSRSLLLRFLLFLLLLPPLP"
aminos = ['M', 'L']

# Count occurrences of all characters
amino_counter = Counter(protein)
total_count = 0

# Only consider the counts of aminos that matter
for amino in aminos:
    total_count += amino_counter.get(amino, 0)

print(total_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. For example,

1. You could keep track of the total count

```
total = 0
for aminos in aa:
    # No need to check if aminos in protein because .count() returns 0 if that's the case
    total += protein.count(aminos)
```

2. You could write a generator expression and use `sum()` to add up all the values for the `count()` of each `amino` in `aa`.

```
total = sum(protein.count(amino) for amino in aa)
```

3. You could iterate over the protein and check if each character is in `aa`. But first, convert `aa` to a `set` to make membership-checks less expensive.

```
s_aa = set(aa)
total = sum(p in s_aa for p in protein)
```

This works because `p in s_aa` evaluates to `True` if `p` is in `s_aa`, and `False` otherwise. `True` counts as one, `False` counts as zero, so when you `sum` a bunch of `True/False` values, you get the number of `True` values.

4. Count all characters in `protein`, then sum the counts for the ones you care about:

```
counts = {}
for p in protein:
    ct = counts.get(p, 0) # get counts[p], default to 0 if not exists
    counts[p] = ct + 1

total = sum(counts.get(amino, 0) for amino in aa)
```

[Vignesh's `collections.Counter` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917132/843953) is the same as this approach. It's better than [Hamza's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917281/843953) for counting the elements because it iterates over the `protein` string just once instead of once for each element of `aa`. This is also the reason my third or fourth approaches are better than #1 and #2.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be:

```
sum(protein.count(a) for a in aa)
```

You can also get indivdual counts as:

```
all_counts = {a:protein.count(a) for a in aa}
```

results in: `{'M': 1, 'L': 10}`

Which you can further sum if you only need the total count:

```
sum(all_counts.values())
```

which results in: `11`

Comment: The list comprehension isn't necessary with `sum()` because the function takes a generator expression. `sum(protein.count(a) for a in aa)` is better because it won't have to make two passes over the list to calculate the sum.

Comment: Ohh yeah! Absolutely I'll fix it